# Converter e editar imagens com jquery e php

Tags: php, jquery, imagem

Tenho uma grade duvida que não consigo encontrar na internet nem em vídeo aulas. Preciso de uma classe para upload de imagem, o que eu preciso é:

- Na hora que a pessoa escolher a imagem, ira abrir uma caixa onde a pessoa terá que selecionar uma parte da imagem para ser cortada.
- Ao terminar de preencher o formulário, esta imagem terá que ir para um arquivo php ou sera convertida em determinado formato, renomeada e movida para uma pasta, e o nome desta imagem e guardado no banco de dados.

Bom tirando a primeira parte, a segunda eu consegui fazer com a classe WideImage, porêm quando eu coloco online, as vezes ela da erro do nada, ai você da um refresh na pagina e ela volta a funcionar!

Mas não consegui criar uma caixa de seleção para foto antes de ser enviado para a WideImage.

Bom o unico jeito e pedir ajuda para quem entende, qualquer dica eu aceito pessoal, obrigado!